# When the script fails, it doesn't do the echo "TEXT" >> FILE

Tags: shell, scripting, echo

I have a script that at the beginning and at the end of it, there is an:

```
echo "start" >> log 
echo "end" >> log
```

The casuistry is that when the script fails uncontrollably, I don't see any line in the LOGS file. However, when the script finishes correctly, the logs are visible in the LOG.

Does somebody knows why it could be?

Comment: Welcome on SO . Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Comment: `I don't see any line in the LOGS` - don't you see `start` in your log file?

Comment: "Why" could be a huge number of things; maybe you start a separate program that deletes `log` when it exits nonzero. If you don't show us, how can we know? We don't need/want your *actual* code, but we *do* need the shortest possible code that lets us experience the specific problem ourselves when run without changes, and test when it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the standard stderr is 2, the default log output just show only stdout from 1. Make a test and show the results. If you make all the script send to log only im one line, make this after define the log file:

```
log_file="/tmp/script.log"
exec >> $log_file 2>&1
```

Comment: They're saying that even the line `start` isn't in the output file after an error occurs. That line is on stdout, not stderr. Why do you expect redirecting stderr to make any difference to whether the output file contains `start`?

Comment: By the way, you have your option to edit your existing answers, as opposed to adding additional ones

Answer (score -1):

you need to direct the error output (2) to standard stdout:

```
echo "start" >> log 2>&1
echo "end" >> log 2>&1
```

Comment: If stdout emitted directly by `echo` can't be written to the file, why would stderr behave any differently?